# How can a git checkout or deployment avoid overwriting non source code files and directories in the working directory?

Tags: git, drupal, git-checkout

I am currently using Git locally for my current Drupal installation, and I want to convert to working from a remote repository which I will clone for use in a development installation.

If after testing the updates and upgrades  on the development version proves safe, I will then push it to the main repo and pull it from there into the working installation.

Is there a possibility that refreshing from the remote and checking out some branches might overwrite the other files in the Drupal directory which are not under git control, like media files, documents etc? Are there checkout commands which a designed to avoid that kind of situation?

Answer (score 1):

Gitignore is the way to go I think. Drupal typically stores your files (like media, documents and all that stuff) under sites/default/files. If you add that folder to your .gitignore file then all of that is ignored and won't override the server when you push it.

A typical Drupal .gitignore file looks like this:

```
# Ignore configuration files that may contain sensitive information.
sites/*/settings*.php

# Ignore paths that contain user-generated content.
sites/*/files
sites/*/private
```

Comment: I am not concerned with the wrong files being added to the repository. It is a checkout I am concerned with, and I don't want the checkout to delete files in the directory which are not part of the site's Drupal code.

Comment: You should check this reply here then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232126/will-a-git-checkout-delete-files-that-shouldnt-be-there